# Extract a string in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have the following string value that comes from a YAML file. I want to extract the first two parts of the string within the terraform file. Let me know how it can be done. I tried the split function.

String: "sg:dev:crm"

Expected value: "sg:dev"

Tried: split(":","sg:dev:crm")[1,2] // This doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to split it into two separate values and concatenate them. For example:

```
locals {
  sg           = "sg:dev:crm"
  split_sg     = split(":","sg:dev:crm")
  wanted_str   = "${local.split_sg[0]}:${local.split_sg[1]}" 
}
```

Also, you tried referencing wrong indexes after you split the string because indexes start from 0, and `sg` is at index 0 while `dev` is at index 1.